# How to detect "late" audio streams in MPEG-2 TS (with ffmpeg, ffprobe or mediainfo)?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, audio, conversion, mpeg

I am recording from my Linux TV-Sat receiver in MPEG-2 transport stream (mpeg2video) format. The recording starts before the actual movie, so it usually only has a single (local) audio stream in the beginning, which is correctly detected by ffmpeg or mediainfo:

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '20131112 2012 - Sky Cinema - Django Unchained.ts':
  Duration: 02:43:02.20, start: 5841.428544, bitrate: 3898 kb/s
  Program 8 
  Program 9 
  Program 10 
    Stream #0:0[0x20](deu): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:1[0x1ff]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x200](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
  Program 11 
  Program 20 
  Program 43 
  Program 251 
  Program 261 
  Program 3499 
  Program 3500 
  Program 3847 
  Program 4021 
  Program 4022 
  Program 4024
```

Note the value for 'start' is taken from the recording itself when no explicit start value was given to ffmpeg by means of `-ss` or `(a)trim=`.

However, after some time, a second (eg english) audio stream is coming along, and it can well be used in the conversion from .ts to .mp4 (for example):

```
Input #0, mpegts, from '20131112 2012 - Sky Cinema - Django Unchained.ts':
  Duration: 02:43:02.20, start: 5841.428544, bitrate: 3898 kb/s
  Program 8 
  Program 9 
  Program 10 
    Stream #0:0[0x20](deu): Subtitle: dvb_teletext ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006)
    Stream #0:1[0x1ff]: Video: mpeg2video (Main) ([2][0][0][0] / 0x0002), yuv420p(tv, top first), 720x576 [SAR 64:45 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:2[0x200](deu): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:3[0x201](eng): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, 192 kb/s (clean effects)
    Stream #0:4[0x203](deu): Audio: ac3 ([6][0][0][0] / 0x0006), 0 channels (clean effects)
  Program 11 
  Program 20 
  Program 43 
  Program 251 
  Program 261 
  Program 3499 
  Program 3500 
  Program 3847 
  Program 4021 
  Program 4022 
  Program 4024 
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (mpeg2video) -> trim
  Stream #0:2 (mp2) -> atrim
  Stream #0:3 (mp2) -> atrim
  setpts -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  asetpts -> Stream #0:1 (aac)
  asetpts -> Stream #0:2 (aac)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
```

(Note: here a value for 'start' was passed to ffmpeg; the value was manually derived and supplied after looking at the recorded .ts file)

Is there a way to detect audio stream(s) without supplying any 'start' value?

Comment: *a value for 'start' was passed to ffmpeg* --> what does this mean?

Comment: Sorry, I was typing too quick. I wanted to say that in the second example, I am using "-ss nnn" as prefix to the input (-i) and/or use (a)trim= in the complex filter to "position" the transcoding process to the beginning of the actual movie within the recording, say after 1 or 2 minutes.